# jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException

Tags: java, rest, jersey

Hello I have some problem with this code! 
   I got this error:
   Please Help!

> org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException:   Validation    of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.
>   [[FATAL] A resource model has ambiguous (sub-)resource method for HTTP method GET and input mime-types as defined by"@Consumes" and "@Produces" annotations at Java methods public java.lang.String jersey.JerseyTesting.getName() and public java.lang.String jersey.JerseyTesting.getPassword() at matching regular expression /jerseytesting. These two methods produces and consumes exactly the same mime-types and therefore their invocation as a resource methods will always fail.; source='org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.RuntimeResource@4d73a7a']
>       org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:555)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:184)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:350)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:255)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.(WebComponent.java:392)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:177)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:369)
>       javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
>       org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>       org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>       org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
>       org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
>       org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
>       org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
>       org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
>       org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
>       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

```
Mine Class:
@Path("/JerseyTesting")
public class JerseyTesting {
String name = "Maks";
String password = "pl000pl";
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
}


Mine web.xml page!
<display-name>JerseyTesting</display-name>  
    <servlet>   
    <servlet-name>JerseyTesting</servlet-name> 
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class> 
    <init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>jersey</param-value>
    </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JerseyTesting</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/RestTesting</url-pattern> 
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> [[FATAL] A resource model has ambiguous (sub-)resource method for HTTP method GET and input mime-types as defined by"@Consumes" and "@Produces" annotations at Java methods public java.lang.String jersey.JerseyTesting.getName() and public java.lang.String jersey.JerseyTesting.getPassword() at matching regular expression /jerseytesting. These two methods produces and consumes exactly the same mime-types and therefore their invocation as a resource methods will always fail.;

Your resource methods are ambiguous

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
```

Jersey will not know which one to pick. You will need to either change the path on one or both of them or the media type. Most likely you will want to change the path for this particular case. Something like

```
@GET
@Path("/name")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
@GET
@Path("/password")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
```

Comment: I changed and now i got "HTTP Status 404 - Not Found"!

Comment: You need to add the new path in the url you're accessing

Comment: Also `<url-pattern>/RestTesting</url-pattern> ` should be `<url-pattern>/RestTesting/*</url-pattern>`

Comment: You might need to go through a good tutorial. Your original question is about the ModelValidationException. And I have answered that question. The 404 is unrelated to this. If you have a different question, please post another question. But any decent tutorial should get you started so you won't get a 404. If you were able to get the app running before, then making the changes I suggested broke it, then that it a different story.

Comment: About what tutorial you are talking about ? Can you give me a link ?

Comment: [Check this out](http://paulsamsotha.blogspot.com/2015/10/getting-started-with-jersey-2.html)

Comment: Search for the Vogella Jersey tutorial